# How to escape non-escaped characters with sed?

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

I would like to use `sed` to escape all non-escaped occurrences of a character, say "&", in a string contained in variable `text`. What I do is

```
text='one&two\&three'
sed 's/\([^\\]\)&/\1\\&/g' <<< "${text}"
```

and I expect the output to be `one\&two\&three`. However, what I get is

```
one\e&two\&three
```

What I (try to) do:

- the search pattern `\([^\\]\)&` should match any occurrence of `&` not preceded by a backslash, and store the character that precedes `&` in `\1`
- the replace pattern `\1\\&` should put a backslash in between `&` and the previous character, however it acts as `\\\1&` for some strange reason

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Why your command fails:**

You did:

```
sed 's/\([^\\]\)&/\1\\&/g' <<< "${text}"
```

- `[^\\]\` matches any character except `\`, and put that in matched group 1, then `&` matches a literal `&`. So for `one&two\&three`, this will match `e` before first `&`, put that in captured group 1. For the `&` before `three` this won't be matched as `\` is before `&`
- In the replacement you have used `\1\\&`, so the output becomes `one\e&two\&three` because:

  - `\1` is replaced by `e`
  - then two `\\`s is treated as single `\`. that gives us `e\` till now
  - then `&` will match the full match i.e. `e&` i.e. `&` will not be escaped as you were thinking
- So, the matched portion i.e. `e&` is replaced with `e\e&`

  You would get the desired result, if you were using another `\` before `&` (As two `\\` make one `\`, so you need one before `&` too:

  ```
  sed 's/\([^\\]\)&/\1\\\&/g' <<<"${text}"
  ```

  As Ubuntu's `sed` supports ERE (Extended Regular Expression), you can use the `-E` or -`r` option to enable that to get rid of the `()`s while capturing:

  ```
  sed -E 's/([^\\])&/\1\\\&/g' <<<"${text}"
  ```

---

**Alternate approach:**

First, removing `\`s before all `&`s, and then adding `\` before all `&`:

```
sed -E 's/[\]+(&)/\1/g; s/&/\\&/g'
```

This is composed of two `sed` statements:

- `s/[\]+(&)/\1/g` removes all `\`s before `&` in the string (line)
- `s/&/\\&/g` adds a `\` too all `&` in the string (line)

---

**Example:**

```
% text='one&two\&three'                       

% sed 's/\([^\\]\)&/\1\\\&/g' <<< "${text}"
one\&two\&three

% sed -E 's/([^\\])&/\1\\\&/g' <<< "${text}" 
one\&two\&three

% sed -E 's/[\]+(&)/\1/g; s/&/\\&/g' <<<"$text"
one\&two\&three
```

Comment: This works great, thanks! But just for curiosity, do you have any ideas as to why my approach fails?

Comment: @AndreasT Check my edits.